# iOS: Best way to parse html tags?

Tags: html, ios, parsing

In my JSON app I'm parsing the JSON data well but the issue is some elements are formatted  as so:

`<b>Welcome!</b>`

(to give a very basic example!)

I've checked for a unformatted version but there doesn't appear to be one, so what's my best option for some basic parsing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at 'libxml2`?

Comment: ios should have a DOM parser in it somewhere. use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class for XPath http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html.

You can parse XML and HTML tags in easy way.

```
NSArray *PerformXMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
```

enjoy