# Parse Facebook Feed Json Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to parse a facebook feed.

Here is my json Url: http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=199009743552420&format=json

So I got this type of Data in response:

```
 "content": "\u003Ca href=\"\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\u00252Fwatch\u00253Fv\u00253D9_PaHtaKAug\u002526list\u00253DPLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n\u002526index\u00253D1\u002526feature\u00253Dplpp_video&amp;h=0AQEQfrMH&amp;s=1\" id=\"\" title=\"\" target=\"\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;\\\/l.php?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\\u00252Fwatch\\u00253Fv\\u00253D9_PaHtaKAug\\u002526list\\u00253DPLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n\\u002526index\\u00253D1\\u002526feature\\u00253Dplpp_video&amp;h=0AQEQfrMH&amp;s=1&quot;);\" style=\"\" rel=\"nofollow\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/watch?v=9_PaHtaKAug&amp;list=PLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n&amp;index=1&amp;feature=plpp_video&quot;);\">\u003Cimg class=\"img\" src=\"http:\/\/external.ak.fbcdn.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQDshpKwwDhCYH9k&amp;w=130&amp;h=130&amp;url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi2.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252F9_PaHtaKAug\u00252Fmqdefault.jpg\" alt=\"\" style=\"height:90px;\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003Cbr\/>\u003Ca href=\"\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\u00252Fwatch\u00253Fv\u00253D9_PaHtaKAug\u002526list\u00253DPLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n\u002526index\u00253D1\u002526feature\u00253Dplpp_video&amp;h=PAQEzb06t&amp;s=1\" id=\"\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;\\\/l.php?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.youtube.com\\u00252Fwatch\\u00253Fv\\u00253D9_PaHtaKAug\\u002526list\\u00253DPLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n\\u002526index\\u00253D1\\u002526feature\\u00253Dplpp_video&amp;h=PAQEzb06t&amp;s=1&quot;);\" style=\"\" rel=\"nofollow\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/watch?v=9_PaHtaKAug&amp;list=PLc4q0uG_h6x5tA_L3kHK6TE9TV6skf14n&amp;index=1&amp;feature=plpp_video&quot;);\">The Dissident Files - Ausama Monajed at THiNK 2012\u003C\/a>\u003Cbr\/>www.youtube.com\u003Cbr\/>Ausama Monajed in conversation with NDTV&#039;s Vishnu Som in Tehelka&#039;s THiNK 2012 session on &quot;The Troubled Looking Glass: Why You Should Care About Syria&quot; For mo... "
```

It contains image logo url, video url, .... so how can I parse this type of data?

Please help me.

Thanking You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661845/json-parser-example-for-ios5

Comment: @Ultrakorne i know how to parse json data but i want to parse data for @"Content" key

Comment: Once you have the string of the content json field, its html code.

Comment: @pdrcabrod i got that but how to separate them

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the content field parsed from the json, you will need to parse it again keeping in mind that now you are dealing with html code. If you want to do some complex queries you will have to use XPath with the libxml2 library.

See: [iOS: Best way to parse html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704563/ios-best-way-to-parse-html-tags)

If you only want to do a simple query, you can iterate over the string and picking what you want